# ¿Cómo ejecutar cmd con archivo .bat?

Tags: cmd

Buenas tardes, necesito realizar la ejecución automática de comandos en el command prompt pero algunos de esos comandos necesitan ejecutarse como adminsitrador.

> ¿Cuál sería el comando que me permita ejecutar el cmd como
>   administrador y que pueda ejecutar los correspondientes comandos?

Gracias.

Comment: Carmen, no has realizado el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Te sugiero también revises [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas, por lo pronto te agrego un tutorial en espanol: https://norfipc.com/utiles/tutorialbatch1.html

Comment: Gracias por la observación, he buscado y he encontrado la solución https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29672528/how-to-run-a-command-prompt-run-as-a-administrator-using-batch-file

Comment: clic derecho y "ejecutar como administrador"

Comment: desafortunadamente ese no es un comando, que es lo que el se solicitó. Te recomiendo leer [Te he votado negativamente porque tu respuesta es totalmente incorrecta.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2912)

Answer (score 3):

Para llamar la linea de comandos crea un archivo .bat, y dentro define el comando `CMD`, de esta forma al ejecutar tu archivo .bat y se abrira la ventana de la linea de comandos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

para ejecutar como administrador los comandos definidos dentro de tu archivo .bat, una forma es ejecutar el archivo como administrador, dando clic derecho y seleccionado la opción:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

o puedes llamar el archivo que creaste mediante linea de comandos:

```
runas /user:<Nombre usuario> /savecred "<ruta hacia el archivo>\archivo.bat"
```

Para comprobar si tu archivo tiene los permisos necesarios para llamar el comando CMD, de otra forma termina ejecución, este sería el archivo .bat

@echo off

```
goto check_Permissions

:check_Permissions
    echo Administrative permissions required. Detecting permissions...

    net session >nul 2>&1
    if %errorLevel% == 0 (
        echo Ok Permisos de adminitrador, abre linea de comandos.
        pause
        CMD
    ) else (
        echo Permisos inadecuados.      
        pause       
    )

    pause >nul
```

Answer (score 0):

Existe un comando "runas" con el cual se ejecutan las aplicaciones para un usuario determinado, no necesariamente administrador, aunque es el más empleado. Accede al propio cmd y solicita la ayuda de este comando para que veas las diferentes opciones... De todas formas para ejecutar una consola con permisos administrativos sería algo como esto: runas  /user:administrador cmd
Saludos,
Klueze.

Answer (score 0):

Crea un archivo .bat con estas características :

```
runas /noprofile /user:nombre de tu pc\administrator cmd
```

Recuerda cambiar **nombre de tu pc** por el nombre de tu máquina

Espero haberte ayudado

De igual forma, si te ayudó esto puedes votar a favor de mi respuesta y marcarla con una palomita